# Second Generation Unlocked Packages without Namespace not including components

Tags: salesforcedx, package, namespace, second-generation-packaging

I'm trying to create a package version for an Unlocked Package with no namespace specified. I can verify this works when running force:package:list and force:package:version:list. I'm including some components that can only be added to packages without a namespace, such as ApprovalProcess and ExperienceBundle(This is speicified in the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/48)). However, even though my packages create just fine, they won't install in scratch org or sandbox. When viewing the install URL so I can view all the components in my package, all the components are added as expected EXCEPT the "no namespace" components. Does anyone know how to ensure the "no namespace" components are added to a package?

Comment: Are they in same path specified in sfdx-project.json file ?

Comment: Yes, all the files are in the same path.

Comment: Have you raised a case for this ? This could be a bug!